# Django URL with {% URL %} from data string

Tags: django, url

I am trying to pass string information into a {% URL %}

I am getting the data from data like:

```
    {% for p in proj %}

      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="{% url  {{ p.dir }} %}"> {{ p.name }} </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

The expected result would be something like:

```
<a href="{% url "path" %}">Sample Info</a>
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

> The first argument is a URL pattern name. It can be a quoted literal or **any other context variable.**

So you need to use `{% url p.dir %}`

Comment: ok, that was way too simple.  I was thinking something more complicated. Thanks!